# Calculate BMI and update BMI Column and update BMI in to range in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

I need to calculate BMI and put that value to catagarize in that into range as ( < 18, 18-24.9 ).

Below are my queries, but the results are incorrect.

My program is in PHP and using Mysql

```
 mysql_query("UPDATE ncd  SET BMI =WeightKG/(HightM*HightM)"); 

mysql_query("UPDATE ncd  SET BMIrage =2 WHERE BMI >18 AND BMI <25  ");
mysql_query("UPDATE ncd  SET BMIrage = 3 WHERE  BMI >=25 AND BMI<= 30");
```

Comment: what error it shows ??

Comment: Better you write like this mysql_query("UPDATE ncd  SET BMI =(WeightKG/(HightM*HightM))") or die (mysql_error());

Comment: with this  you will get exact error from the mysql query

Comment: I don't see an update statement for < 18 and the database view has a field name of BMIraNge but your update statement has BMIrage?

Comment: Sorry for late reply .In  ncd database I got BMI field correctly . but Zero for BMIrange Field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update code in the following way:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE ncd  SET BMIrange =1 WHERE BMI < 18.00");
mysql_query("UPDATE ncd  SET BMIrange =2 WHERE BMI >18.00 AND BMI <25.00  ");
mysql_query("UPDATE ncd  SET BMIrange = 3 WHERE  BMI >=25.00 AND BMI<= 30.00");
```

Comment: thanks It works . in my program there was a spelling mistake also

Comment: @Nimna you are talking about BMIrange which was BMIrage. I had changed that also.

Comment: @Nimna please accept it as the ans if it worked for you

Comment: i am new to stackoverflow  , so please let me know the procedure

Comment: @Nimna, there will be a transparent tick mark near my ans. Just click on it and the question will be marked as answered